# Level 3 squirtle water gun attack

Tags: pokemon

Can a level three Squirtle blast a hole through your chest with water gun attack.

What are the actual capabilities of a level three water gun attack. Could they really kill people. Should people be concerned for their lives if threatened by a level three Squirle?

Comment: related / unrelated https://jgeekstudies.org/2015/06/16/turtles-with-cannons/

Comment: https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/docket/archive/pdfs/niosh-125/125-explosionsandrefugechambers.pdf

Comment: Is your question related to the anime? Otherwise, I advise you to ask your question on the gaming stackexchange, you might get more on-point and accurate answers

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: From what I recall from the anime, several strong Pokémon have to use Water Gun to force a steel plate from a wall, so I can't imagine one weak Squirtle punching a hole through your chest with a Water Gun.

Moreover, there is no way a Squirtle is even able to use Water Gun at level 3 except in gen I. Water Gun is not learned until levels 13 or 7 (depending on the generation), does not pass down through breeding and Squirtles do not learn it through TM's except in gen I. [Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Squirtle_(Pok%C3%A9mon)/Generation_I_learnset#By_leveling_up), you can check all gens.